# How can I force 3G only on the Nexus S after the ICS update?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-nexus-s, 3g

In earlier versions of Android there was an option to toggle data between 2G, 3G preferred and 3G only.  After the ICS 4.0.3 update for Nexus S, there is no option for "3G only".

Did Google lock down this option or is there a way to force "3G only"? I don't care about connection quality or battery, I just want my data to stay in "3G only" mode.

Comment: I've been using Android since it was released to the public, and I've never noticed a "3G only" option.

Comment: I've only used it since Gingerbread but I haven't seen a '3G only' option either, just the 2G only that I mention in my answer.

Comment: This _may_ be specific to the Galaxy Nexus, but I find the setting under `Settings | Wireless & Networks | More... | Mobile networks | Network Mode` and setting it to "CDMA" (instead of "LTE/CDMA").

Comment: I have a Galaxy Nexus but don't have that option, I assume that's because we don't have 4G over here in the UK yet so there's no need for it.

Answer (score 3):

There's an app for 3G only mode:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobnetic.only3G

However your phone should automatically try and go for 3G if there's a 3G connection available, it will never choose 2G over 3G so I don't see why this would be useful... There's still a 2G only mode to save battery in Settings -> Mobile Networks

Answer (score 2):

Enter `*#*#4636#*#*` in your dialer and select "3g only" mode on the menu that opens.

Comment: I used this code `*#*#4636#*#*` and I it enters a secret menu where I can choose "WCDMA ONLY" but I cannot save it . After exit it returns to "GSM/WCDMA" in automatic. All this on my GALAXY S2 with Android 2.3 Gingerbread

Comment: "this number does not exist" is all I get under this number. But also those many apps that are made to activate this option as an app, as in the answer by Peanut only report that this is not supported on my phone, although they all open a menu above which the error message is displayed.